# Soap Product List Output - Magento

Tags: php, api, magento, soap

I have tried using the Magento API documentation via SOAP times output my product list, the whole thing looks like this: 
(http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html)

```
<?php
//include the Magento API file - replace with your server path to the file
require_once('/absolut-dirl/app/Mage.php');

/***** Configuration ******/
$myAPILogin = 'login';
$myAPIKey = 'key';


// Begin SOAP Requests
$client = new SoapClient('https://shop-url.com/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login($myAPILogin, $myAPIKey);

//get all my database products into an array
$products = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.list');

echo "Starting product loop...<br/><br/>";
var_dump($products);
?>
```

However, I always get NULL as a result. What am I doing wrong?
About fast help, I would appreciate it.

Greetings 
Roley

// Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Is that really the URL you are using ("shop-url.com"), probably copied and pasted from the documentation, or is that a sanitised URL, to hide the real domain here?

Comment: I hide the real domain

Answer (score 0):

Its may be problem with login credential. Use try catch block and check.

```
try
{
    $proxy  = new SoapClient($magento_webserver."api/soap/?wsdl");
    $sessionId  = $proxy->login($magento_webservices_username,  $magento_webservices_passwd);
    echo "Soap login complete! <br/>";
    echo "======================== <br/>";
}
catch (SoapFault $fault)
{
    die("\n\n SOAP Fault: (fault code: {$fault->faultcode},
    fault string: {$fault->faultstring}) <br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the try-catch block and get the following result:

```
Soap Login complete!
========================
```